# Running heavy php file in background without cronjobs

Tags: php

How can I run a php file IN BACKGROUND after submitting a form. The loading has to happen in background since it usually takes a very long time.

Basically it's just like running a cronjob, except I want to trigger it manually and with my browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways to do this.

1. Try setting [`ignore_user_abort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) to TRUE in your script.
   *If changed to TRUE scripts will not be terminated after a client has aborted their connection.*
2. Take a look at [`popen()`](https://www.php.net/popen) and [`pclose()`](https://www.php.net/pclose). You can do something like this:

   `pclose(popen("start php /path/to/myscript.php", "r"));`
3. You can kick off a separate PHP process with a [`system()`](https://www.php.net/system) or [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) call. Something like this:

`system('php /path/to/myscript.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');`

Comment: pclose doesn't seem to work and with system I get "No input file specified."

Comment: I'm using #2 and #3 both in a production app. #2 on Windows, #3 on Linux. Double check all your paths, sounds like you've got something else going on.

Comment: Ensure that you can open a command prompt and execute `php /path/to/myscript.php` directly from the terminal, with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Start the request using AJAX. The browser will continue running while waiting for a response. You can even show a popup or some information when the request is finished, although you don't have to.

Comment: That way the user would have to wait until the file finishes loading, right? I want to be able to close my browser right after the request but still have the file continue loading on server side.